# Device Wifi Setup Walkthrough

Tags: wifi-direct

Most electronic home goods today are able to be setup through a webpage to connect the device to a home network. Usually there is some sort of bluetooth or wifi direct finding mode to access the device and then using a webpage or app the device is given the SSID/password for a wifi network and then you're off to the races. What is that tech called? I would like to replicate the setup experience with a generic IoT device running linux. I just don't know what that process is called to start digging into how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth and Wifi-direct specifications are (consumer-usage-wise) public-domain knowledge, just setup a temporary open server and accept any connection after each hard-reset, and do what you have to do like [here (BT)](https://robotzero.one/esp32-wi-fi-connection-bluetooth/) and [here (Wifi-direct)](https://www.teachmemicro.com/esp32-wifi-manager-dynamic-ssid-password/). There are other proprietary technology like [TI CC3000](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/61704/how-does-ti-cc3000-wifi-smart-config-work), which usually relates to specific hardware solutions.